# OpenGL C code works on Mac OS X but not on Linux

Tags: opengl, x11

I'm a novice C programmer and this is my first time working with graphics. I was given some code that includes some OpenGL functionality that works properly on my MacBook Pro (running OS X version 10.6.8), but it won't compile on my office machine that is running Linux (CentOS version 2.16.0). In both cases I am using gcc. I pass the following options when compiling on the Mac:

```
-lcurses -lX11 -lGL -lm -fast 
-I/usr/X11R6/include/ -I/usr/X11R6/include/GL -L/usr/X11R6/lib 
-L/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries 
-Wl,-dylib_file,/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib:/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib
```

When attempting to compile on Linux with the following options

```
-lcurses -lX11 -lGL -lm
```

I get the following errors

```
cem_master.c:159: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
cem_master.c:160: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
cem_master.c:161: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
```

which refer to the following lines of code:

```
static WINDOW *mainwnd;
static WINDOW *screen;
WINDOW *my_win;
```

Any ideas on what is wrong? Tips on how to go about understanding this?

---

In response to the comment, here's a reduced version of the source code from the first line to the section that is causing the errors. I cut out a lot of junk between the includes and the /*Display Crap*/ section, but this still produces the errors.

```
#include <stdlib.h>      
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <GL/glx.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* Display Crap */
static WINDOW *mainwnd;
static WINDOW *screen;
WINDOW *my_win;

float   xcellwidth;
float   ycellwidth;
int     current_getch;
int     xplotoff;
int     yplotoff;

Display                 *dpy;
Window                  root;
XVisualInfo             *vi;
Colormap                cmap;
XSetWindowAttributes    swa;
Window                  win;
GLXContext              cx;
XEvent                  event;
```

Comment: Post the entire source file, or at least the fragment from the very first line up to the lines that cause the errors.

Answer (score 0):

`WINDOW` and `SCREEN` are from the `ncurses` library. You need to `#include <ncurses.h>` to use it.

Comment: Looks like I don't have have ncurses. Do you know how I can get/install it? Do I need administrator privileges?

Comment: Use your distro's package manager. Install the dev (or devel) version of the package. You do need administrator privileges to install things. There are ways around it (install from sources in your $HOME) but I do not recommend it for a beginner.